# Angular always running checks

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In our current Angular application I found one strange behavior. Example:

```
angular.module('app.book')
    .directive('ddBook', function () {
        return {
            scope: {},
            replace: true,
            controller: 'BookCtrl',
            controllerAs: 'ctrl'
        };
    })
    .controller('BookCtrl',
        [
            '$scope',
            function ($scope) {


                $scope.isPrebookingAllowed = function () {
                    //if I set here break point it will always be hited
                    return true;
                };

            }
        ]);
```

Some HTML of this directive

```
<div ng-show="isPrebookingAllowed()">
   //something goes here
</div>
```

The problem is that if I set break point on isPrebookingAllowed method it will always hit it. It's seams like I have infinity loop and something is triggering this directives digest loop, but I don't do any changes to UI.

Comment: If you didn't make any changes to the UI (inadvertent or otherwise) and you didn't call isPrebookingAllowed in another place, then you would have no issue.  Since you do, the content of isPrebookingAllowed is relevant and your issue can't be resolved without seeing how you wrote it.

Comment: Also just to note a watcher is registered to `isPrebookingAllowed` thanks to `ngShow`. This means when ever a digest cycle is run in the entirety of that application angular will generally check all of its registered watchers to update any databinding. As `isPrebookingAllowed` is a function is means it will be executed. I say generally because angular probably does things to optimize performance but it does mean `isPrebookingAllowed` could get called when your not doing anything in the directive to directly cause it. This is my understanding of the digest cycle at least.

Comment: `isPrebookingAllowed` function is getting called on each digest cycle..don;t worry about it.. Its normal in angular

Comment: AngularJS calll $digest() frequently to track any changes in JS to provide two way binding. In other word Angularjs's digest cycle runs always to check any changes in your application(view or controller).

Comment: It's not true. Look at my example http://plnkr.co/edit/lhzLH35lGfAauzGWubRo?p=preview ifTextIsCat method is called only If I type text. Angular digest not run always, it run only if needed. Basically then event(input,change, click, hover...), http request, timeout and other things occur.

Comment: @AndzejMaciusovic You are correct, can you provide a fiddle/plunker replicating your issue? And as Neil says where else is `isPrebookingAllowed ` getting called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular will update the DOM on every digest cycle. Where it can, it optimises this by watching for specific items to change. So if you do:

```
<div ng-show="ctrl.isPrebookingAllowed">
   //something goes here
</div>
```

it will simply check the value of ctrl.isPreBookingAllowed for changes and if it hasn't changed nothing happens.

However if you call a function Angular can't tell whether the result may have changed, so it will call it every time:

```
<div ng-show="ctrl.isPrebookingAllowed()">
   //something goes here
</div>
```

If the code is short a large number of calls may not matter. Otherwise try to make your code set values in scope or on the controller (if you use 'controller as'), especially if the expression is inside a repeat and you end up with a lot of them.

I think in this case it is likely that some other code which you haven't posted is triggering the digest loop. Again the way to fix this would be to evaluate the expression only when it might change and store the result on the scope.